# Callback method giving a nullpointer exception Android

Tags: java, android, callback, autocompletetextview

I am trying to instantiate an autocompleteTextview and I have an adapter which populates contactlist. Once the user selects a contact, I am passing the mobile number to a callback method.

Here is my callback interface.

```
public interface OnTaskCompleted {
        void taskCompleted(String errorMessage);
}
```

Here is how i instantiate my custom autocompleteTextview.

```
myListener = new OnTaskCompleted() {

            @Override
            public void taskCompleted(String errorMessage) {


            }
        };
        SingleSelectContactmToField = new SingleSelectContact(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), myListener);
```

Here is my class SingleSelectContact.

```
 public class SingleSelectContact extends MultiAutoCompleteTextView implements OnItemClickListener {
    private OnTaskCompleted mListener; 
    public SingleSelectContact(Context context, OnTaskCompleted listener) {
            super(context);
            init(context);
            mListener = listener;
        }
        /* Constructor */
        public SingleSelectContact(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            init(context);
        }
        /* Constructor */
        public SingleSelectContact(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            init(context);
        }
        /* set listeners for item click and text change */
        public void init(Context context){
            setOnItemClickListener(this);
            addTextChangedListener(textWather);
        } 


            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,    long id) {
    Map<String, String> currentContact = (Map<String, String>)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);   
    String contactName = currentContact.get("Name");
    String contactId = currentContact.get("Number");
    setText(contactName);
    setSelection(getText().length());
            mListener.taskCompleted(contactId ); /*I GET A NULL POINTER EXECLPTION HERE*/
}
```

I have debugged and I can see that in the constructor, the listener gets instantiated properly. But inside onItemClick, the value of mListener is shown to be null.
Help is appreciated. 
Here is the error Log I get

```
E/AndroidRuntime(24202): java.lang.NullPointerException

E/AndroidRuntime(24202):    at com.citrus.citruspay.SingleSelectContact.onItemClick(SingleSelectContact.java:119)

E/AndroidRuntime(24202):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performCompletion(AutoCompleteTextView.java:902)

E/AndroidRuntime(24202):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.access$500(AutoCompleteTextView.java:91)

E/AndroidRuntime(24202):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$DropDownItemClickListener.onItemClick(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1192)

E/AndroidRuntime(24202):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)

E/AndroidRuntime(24202):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1128)

E/AndroidRuntime(24202):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2812)

E/AndroidRuntime(24202):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3571)

E/AndroidRuntime(24202):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)

E/AndroidRuntime(24202):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

E/AndroidRuntime(24202):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)

E/AndroidRuntime(24202):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)

E/AndroidRuntime(24202):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(24202):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

E/AndroidRuntime(24202):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)

E/AndroidRuntime(24202):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)

E/AndroidRuntime(24202):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please provide stack trace?

Comment: edited, please check.

Comment: try assigning the listener first before calling `init(context)`?

Comment: Is there any other instance of SingleSelectContact that is being created with different constructor? Initialize mListener in all the constructors. Put a null check b4 calling taskCompleted() on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your listener directly in your SingleSelectContact definition like following. To create an interface instance, you need to implement it first. So, you cannot create an interface instance like yours, but you can create an implementation for it.

```
SingleSelectContact mToField = new SingleSelectContact(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), new OnTaskCompleted() {

    @Override
    public void taskCompleted(String errorMessage) {


    }
});
```